# Memory management in viewControllers

Tags: iphone, variables, memory, memory-management, view

In my app I have a number of *viewControllers* and in the `viewDidUnload` method of these views I have been setting my variables to `nil` as follows, `myString = nil;` - however I'm wondering if this is the correct method for doing this?

My other *viewControllers* are all closed/dismissed using this line of code `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` however I wasn't sure if this would actually call the `viewDidUnload` method or whether there was a better way of unloading the *viewController*.

I've never been 100% clear on exactly what the rules are on memory management and I know with the new `ARC` features it has become easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Are you using ARC or not ?
2. If not using ARC, `myString = nil` does nothing, it does not release anything (but `self.myString = nil` does)
3. If you store views in `@property(retain)` (or `@property(copy)`) then should set these properties back to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`. (After `iOS6` where `viewDidUnload` is depreacted, you should even release them instead in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and only if `isViewLoaded` is `YES` and `self.view.window` is `nil`)
4. You don't close/dismiss `subviews` using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`. You dismiss `UIViewControllers`. And when you dismiss a viewController, it remove its view from the view hierarchy. Be sure to understand the difference between *views* and *viewControllers* (which are different objects, different parts of the MVC pattern)

Comment: You want to say, if we are not storing variables in  @property(retain) (or @property(copy)) then we should first release it and assign to nil in didReceiveMemoryWarning or viewDidUnload?

Comment: I'm using ARC and I'm not using the @property on my variables. The few where I do I have done `self.myVariable = nil` so those should be taken care of, I was just curious about the other variables. Sorry, about the subview confusion, the views it is dismissing are `viewControllers` - just wondered whether it is necessary to unload these `viewControllers` when they're no longer in use / in view. Along with the variables used in them.

Comment: @NuzhatZari yes if you don't use `@properties` but only instance variables, and don't use ARC, then you have to manage the memory yourself. When the view of your viewController is unloaded because of a memoryWarning (in `viewDidUnload` until now, and in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in future versions after iOS6 as `viewDidUnload` will not exist in later versions), then you should also release every subviews of your view that you previously retained yourself.

Comment: @KarlDaniel if you use ARC you should store your subviews in `weak` variables, so that it is automatically released and set to nil when the subviews are removed from the view hierarchy (especially when your main view is being unloaded). If you can't use `weak` variables for some of your views (because you sometimes remove them from your main view and add them later, for example, depending on some conditions, etc…) and thus store them in `strong` instance variables, you need to set these ivars back to `nil` in `viewDidUnload` for their memory to be reclaimed in that case.

Comment: I'm using *viewControllers* rather than *subViews* at that are called and presented to the user when they press or do something in the app. Is it the same practice?

Comment: I'm not sure your answer make really sense… `UIViewControllers` are *controllers*. The control the behavior of the view they present. `UIViews` are views, that are displayed on screen. Are you sure you understand the difference in the MVC pattern? If you display your views by asking viewControllers to present their views modally, the memory logic to manage the root view of your `UIViewController` is in the `UIViewController` itself (`viewDidUnload` is a method of `UIViewController`). That's also one of the use of **viewcontrollers**, to control the lifetime of a view.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough. What I'm trying to say is that when I go from one viewController to another viewController (e.g by pressing a button) is it necessary to do anything to that viewController that was left. Such as unloading specific variables, views etc...

Comment: No nothing to do directly. You only have to implement `viewDidUnload` correctly (i.e. if not using ARC, releasing the subviews you were retaining). When you push or present a viewController on top of another, the first VC and its view still exist in memory as long there is enough RAM on your iPhone. If you got a memoryWarning at some point in your application, every VC whose view is not visible on screen (typically every VC below the one visible) will unload their view to reclaim some memory, and `viewDidUnload` will then be called to allow you to release the memory of your subviews & outlets

Comment: @AliSoftware For the last point, 1.when I dismissed/present a `UIViewController`, should I need to set it to nil after setting others to nil? 2. should I call `[self.view removeFromSuperView]` also? in this case `self.view` is inside the dismissed viewController. 3. and I need to set those `self.objectArray` to nil which is some data of dismissed vc? 4. when should I set vc's `delegate` to nil?

Answer (score 1):

**Simply** u **define** NSString *myString and do

```
myString = nil;
```

Then it sets null pointer to myString but doesnot release memory if it was referred to.

Now if u create @**property** of NSString *myString then:

```
self.myString = nil;
```

it releases memory if it was referred to  and adds null pointer.

Now in **ARC** there is **no need to release** objects as it release automatically but just **use wisely**.

In **non-ARC**, u **need to release** memory that allocated or referenced.